# How to move specific item in array list to the first item

Tags: java, android, collections, arraylist, swap

For example : A list

A B C D E

Given C , Switch to

C A B D E

Notice that the array size will change, some items may removed in run times

```
Collections.swap(url, url.indexOf(itemToMove), 0);
```

This statement is not working because it output C B A D E not C A B D E , how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

What you want is a very expensive operation in an `ArrayList`. It requires shifting every element between the beginning of the list and the location of `C` down by one.

However, if you really want to do it:

```
int index = url.indexOf(itemToMove);
url.remove(index);
url.add(0, itemToMove);
```

If this is a frequent operation for you, and random access is rather less frequent, you might consider switching to another `List` implementation such as `LinkedList`. You should also consider whether a list is the right data structure at all if you're so concerned about the order of elements.

Comment: if speed is a criteria, then maybe you should also look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/TreeList.html

Comment: @Aditya broken link now.

Comment: Here is the new link - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/TreeList.html

Answer (score 22):

Do this:

1. ***Remove*** the element from the list: `ArraylistObj.remove(object);`
2. ***Add*** the element **back** to the list ***at specific position***: `ArrayListObj.add(position, Object);`

As per your code use this :

```
url.remove("C");
url.add(0,"C");
```

Comment: isn't it will increase the size of list?

Comment: Then remove the element from list by using url.remove("C"); and add element at zero position by using url.add(0,"C");

Answer (score 14):

Another solution, just keep swaping from `0` to `indexOf(itemToMove)`.

This is my Kotlin version:

```
val list = mutableListOf('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
(0..list.indexOf('C')).forEach {
    Collections.swap(list, 0, it)
}
```

Sorry I am unfamiliar with Java but learned a little Kotlin. But the algorithm is the same.

Comment: It gives "C, B, A, D, E" on output instead of "C, A, B, D, E".

Comment: @lazarevzubov you can test it at Kotlin Playground, e.g. https://pl.kotl.in/OwYLJ_SZ-

Comment: My apologies...

Answer (score 10):

The problem is, you swap C with A, so A B C D E becomes C B A D E.

You could try something like this:

```
url.remove(itemToMove);
url.add(0, itemToMove);
```

Or if `url` is a `LinkedList`:

```
url.remove(itemToMove);
url.addFirst(itemToMove);
```

Answer (score 4):

One more Kotlin solution based on other answers from this thread:

```
inline fun <T> List<T>.moveItemToFirstPosition(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<T> {
    for (element in this.withIndex()) {
        if (predicate(element.value)) {
            return this.toMutableList().apply {
                removeAt(element.index)
                add(0, element.value)
            }.toList()
        }
    }
    return this
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
list = list.moveItemToFirstPosition { it == "C" }
```

OR

```
inline fun <T> MutableList<T>.moveItemToFirstPosition(predicate: (T) -> Boolean) {
    for (element in this.withIndex()) {
        if (predicate(element.value)) {
            removeAt(element.index)
            add(0, element.value)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
val list = mutableListOf("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
list.moveItemToFirstPosition { it == "C" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin ->

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.move(item: T, newIndex: Int)  {
    val currentIndex = indexOf(item)
    if (currentIndex < 0) return
    removeAt(currentIndex)
    add(newIndex, item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will allow you to increase size of list, and insert elements without otherwise disturbing order of list

```
private void insert(double price){
    for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++){
        if(price > keys.get(i)){
            keys.add(null);
            for(int j = keys.size()-1; j > i; j--){
                Collections.swap(keys, j, j-1);
            }
            keys.add(price);
            Collections.swap(keys, keys.size()-1, i);
            keys.remove(keys.size()-1);
            return;
        }
    }
    keys.add(price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have an array:

```
String[] arrayOne = new String[]{"A","B","C","D","E"};
```

Now you want to place the `C` at index `0` get the `C` in another variable

```
String characterC = arrayOne[2];
```

Now run the loop like following:

```
for (int i = (2 - 1); i >= 0; i--) {

            arrayOne[i+1] = arrayOne[i];
        }
```

Above `2` is index of `C`. Now insert `C` at index for example on `0`

```
arrayOne[0] = characterC;
```

Result of above loop will be like that:

```
arrayOne: {"C","A","B","D","E"}
```

The end, we achieve our goal.