# Move item to top of listview when a new message arrives

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, xmpp, android-arrayadapter

I am working on a XMPP based chat in android.. and I am struck at a point where I need to update the position of an item in the listview to the top in case a new.message arrives.

The use case is.. I am on Contacts screen of the app and a new message comes.. so this contact should move to top of the list and get bold. This is what is similar to whatsapp as well

How can this be done. My class imolemebts activity and i have implemented custom list adapter.

So howcan I find if an item exists in the listview and secondly how to dynamically change position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it

```
private void moveMessageToTop(MessageObject message) {
        int index = 0;
        for (Friends friend : mFriends) {
            if (friend.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(message.getFrom().split("@")[0])) {
                index = mFriends.indexOf(friend);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (index != 0) {
            mFriends.add(0,new Friends(message.getFrom().split("@")[0], message
                    .getMessage()));
        } else {
            Friends frnd = mFriends.get(index);
            frnd.setStatus(message.getMessage());
            mFriends.add(0, frnd);
            mFriends.remove(index);
        }

        ((ListAdapter) lvFriends.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, keep in mind that a `ListView` is just a representation of a list of `Objects`. So if you want to know if an item is in the `ListView`, you just have to check if the corresponding `Object` is in your list of `Objects`.

Is the same when you want to change the position of one item, you have to change the position of the `Object` in the list.

Start by defining these objects:

```
private ArrayList<MyObject> lists = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
private MyCustomAdapter myAdapter;
```

The first time you create your `ListView`, just do as usually:

```
//fill your list with your objects
lists.add(myObject1);
lists.add(myObject2);
lists.add(myObject3);
//create and set the adapter
myAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(..., ..., lists);
myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Now you can know if your `lists` contains a specific object (which is the same that checking if an item is in your `ListView`) by simply testing that:

```
lists.contains(anObject);
```

Then, if you want to change the position of a specific item in the `ListView`, you have to create a new list and put the elements in the correct order. You can use something like that (not tested but it should work):

```
private ArrayList<MyObject> moveItemToTop(ArrayList<MyObject> lists, int positionOfItem) {
    if (lists == null || positionOfItem < 0 || positionOfItem >= lists.size()) {
        return lists;
    }

    ArrayList<MyObject> sortedList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    //add the item to the top
    sortedList.add(lists.get(positionOfItem));

    for (int i=0; i<lists.size(); i++) {
        if (i != positionOfItem) {
            sortedList.add(lists.get(i));
        }
    } 

    return sortedList;
}
```

Or even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20186749/3571822) (which is way easier...).

Finally, call these two methods to update your `ListView`:

```
myAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(..., ..., moveItemToTop(lists, itemPosition));
myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Shall try this out.