# Moving ArrayList element to the last position in the List?

Tags: java, arraylist

In the following method I have an `ArrayList` of `Strings`.

I check if any of these strings are in a txt file (`checkIfWordIsInTextFile` method).

If a string is in this list, I want to place it **last** in the List, then return the re-ordered list.

I am trying to use the set method but I'm not sure how to set the string to be the **last element** in the list.

**current method:**

```
 public List<String> placeParentsLastInLineItemList(List<String> listToReorder){

    for(String string: listToReorder){

       if(checkIfWordIsInTextFile(string)==true){
          listToReorder.set(,string); //how to set the string to the last element in list?
       }

    return listToReorder;
 }
```

Comment: just remove it and add it again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving items around in an ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938626/moving-items-around-in-an-arraylist)

Comment: use an iterator

Comment: Not having java installed at this moment, so i cant try and post a solution.. but i have some thing in mind: create a default for loop (for (int i = 0; i<list.length(); i++) etc) so you know the position of the string element, and then just create temp element from that element, and switch it with element in the end of the list (list[list.length()-1]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move specific item in array list to the first item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186681/how-to-move-specific-item-in-array-list-to-the-first-item)

Comment: So I just remove it and re-add it, all within my original for loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Simplest Solution** (for a beginner)

The [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) default [add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) behavior by definition, adds to the end of the list. So:-

```
listToReorder.add(string)
```

You will need to remove it from it's original position though, so **don't** use a for-each loop, use an index, then when you find it:-

```
listToReorder.remove(i);
```

...before re-adding it to the end, so:-

```
for (int i=0; i<listToReorder.size(); i++){
  String item = listToReorder.get(i);

//NOTE: '==true' isn't required if the method returns a boolean
  if(checkIfWordIsInTextFile(item)){ 
//As per  @rishi007bansod suggestion: If we remove an item, then the next item will be shifted into this index & effectively skipped.  Therefore we want the index not to change this time around so decrement i after usage
    listToReorder.remove(i--);
    listToReorder.add(item);
  }
}
```

**Other options**

- You could create a new temporary list and recreate the list in the order you want but that makes for complicated code, as per @Andriy Kryvtsuns answer.  The other problem with this is that you don't know what implementation of `List` was passed in, creating a whole list could be inefficient if, say, a `LinkedList` was passed it and `remove()` can run faster than linear time.

**More advanced options**

- You could use a for-each loop (like @Ash French) but you'd need to use an `Iterator` as for-each loops restrict you from editing Collections you are looping over
- You could get all Java 8 and use a [lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), as per @Mad Matts elegant solution

Comment: @RossDrew this seems a good answer, can you please show how I do this all in the indexed for loop?

Comment: @Ross Simplest Solution will fail where >=2 consecutive elements in list are present in text file. It will fail as list shifts elements after removing elements and we are always increasing index while looping.

Comment: @rishi007bansod well spotted.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already you could `remove`the first occurrence of your string in the list and then add it, or create a new List. But it's also possible to sort your list, so that all words, which are in the text file appear last:

```
listToReorder.sort((s1, s2) -> {
    if (checkIfWordIsInTextFile(s1))
        return 1;
    return -1;
});
```

Comment: Love this. Referenced it in my slightly more basic answer

Answer (score 1):

What I would do would be to use an iterator, then remove the item, and them add them at the end.

```
List<String> toAdd = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator iter = listToReorder.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
   String string = iter.next();
   if(checkIfWordIsInTextFile(string)){
       toAdd.add(string);
       iter.next();
   }
}

listToReorder.addAll(toAdd);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a new `List` instance as a result:

```
public List<String> placeParentsLastInLineItemList(List<String> listToReorder) {
    List<String> inFileList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> notInFileList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String string : listToReorder) {
        (checkIfWordIsInTextFile(string)? inFileList: notInFileList).add(string);
    }
    return joinLists(notInFileList, inFileList);
}

private List<String> joinLists(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(list1);
    result.addAll(list2);
    return result;
}
```

Advantage of this solution is also absence of a side effect in modification of input parameter `listToReorder`.

Comment: create a whole Collection, just to move an item to the end of an existing one?

Comment: @RossDrew can't see any problem with this. But this solution with `foreach` more clear than without it. It's not necessary to do preliminary optimization without real reason.

Comment: This isn't optimization, it's just good coding.  Creating an entire copy of a Collection just to move a single item is wasteful.

Comment: Simple is deleting an element and adding it to the end.  This is complex.
So complex in fact, that you managed to mess up the logic.  It doesn't work.  It builds a string containing only the elements from the file.

Comment: Still convinced this is the simpler solution?

Comment: @RossDrew I fixed my solution. Still don't see any reason to work with input list doing side effect.

Comment: Fixed it but didn't you say "Good code is simple code", it's no longer simple.

Comment: @RossDrew but it's still well understandable and without any side effects. It's usually better then modifying input params.

Comment: This is a piece of learning code, do you think thread access to this collection is going to be an issue?  Didn't you say "It's not necessary to do preliminary optimization without real reason"
You've written code twice as long with an extra method to catch a "side effect" that may be relied upon in program logic, the "spec" does say "then return the re-ordered list." not "return a new list"

Comment: @RossDrew 1. I always write real (non learning) code 2. I haven't mentioned any thread related issues 3. I haven't caught `side effect` specifically. It's a result of good code practices. 4. Initial method signature has return param.

Comment: Return param doesn't state "new object" and the only "side effect" you could be referring to is thread collision.   Either way, in an attempt to write the least complicated code, you've written the most complicated code.